# For..in Loop Array Iteration with Index Position

Tags: javascript

I tried looping over an array with for..in loop and show the index of each item but it showed an error message. Who has an idea of how this thing work?

Comment: Please, show us your code, we are not magicians.

Comment: And describe the nature of the error message, thanks.

Comment: Welcome Joshua! In order for us to help we need as much info as possible. As is, the way the question is worded we have no idea what your for..in loop looks like, how you're showing the index, or what the error message is. We can take some guesses, like you're using a for..in loop instead of a for..of loop on an array, but that's just a guess. It would be super helpful if you can give us all the details.

Answer (score 0):

For arrays you will need to use `for...of` rather than `for...in` which is for iterating over objects.

However, `for...of` will not give you the *index* - only the *value*.

Use `forEach` for this purpose:

```
array.forEach(function (value, index) {

});
```

Comment: You can have the _index_ with `for...of` like this: `for (const [index, value] of [10, 20, 30].entries()) {
  console.log(index, value)
}`